# Requiering data trieve from the table data by T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

[image]

I want to extract data from the `Account_Transaction` table for accounts with more than two credits in the last 4 months. I have included sample data along with a SQL query I have tried, but does not provide the data I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        account_id
       ,transaction_type_id
       ,credit_amount
       ,effective_date
FROM    Account_Transaction
WHERE   transaction_type_id = 1
        AND effective_date BETWEEN '01 feb 2015'
                           AND     '01 may 2015'
GROUP BY account_id
HAVING  COUNT(account_id) > 2
ORDER BY account_id
```

but this seems doesn't fetch the desired output

Comment: What result are you seeing?  You can't `Group By` some of the fields, they should either appear in the list or have an *aggregate* function. Also, you wouldn't be able to group by date here since the grouping would not match.

Comment: This is an analogy I have taken from a real example. My desired output  should  be only 3 records of A1 account.I am not too sure my example would give me the result.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        account_id
       ,transaction_type_id
       ,SUM(credit_amount)
       ,MAX(effective_date)
FROM    Account_Transaction
WHERE   transaction_type_id = 1
        AND effective_date BETWEEN '01 feb 2015'
                           AND     '01 may 2015'
GROUP BY account_id, transaction_type_id
HAVING  COUNT(account_id) > 2
ORDER BY account_id
```

This will sum up the *credit_amount* and show the last *effective_date*.

If you want to list the records for the account that meets the above criteria, you could use a CTE...

```
--the cte will give a list of Account ID's with the criteria
WITH cteAccounts AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT
            account_id
    FROM    Account_Transaction
    WHERE   transaction_type_id = 1
            AND effective_date BETWEEN '01 feb 2015'
                               AND     '01 may 2015'
    GROUP BY account_id
    HAVING  COUNT(account_id) > 2
)

--join against the CTE to get the accounts Id's
SELECT a.account_id
       ,a.transaction_type_id
       ,a.credit_amount
       ,a.effective_date
FROM    Account_Transaction a INNER JOIN cteAccounts b on a.account_id = b.account_id
WHERE   a.transaction_type_id = 1
        AND a.effective_date BETWEEN '01 feb 2015'
                           AND     '01 may 2015'
ORDER BY account_id
```

Comment: Hi Chris.. I am getting error as : incorrect syntax near the keyword WITH.. I tried to pass an argument  to cteAccounts(accountID) but still getting the same error.

Comment: I just realised it was Sybase, take the semi colon away and it should work.  You don't pass any arguments to it.